# generate PDF using TCPDF from MySQL database table and save generated PDF to another MySQL database table and retrieve it from it

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Hello Everyone,
              I am New To TCPDF and My query is that i have successfully generated PDF from MySQL database table A1 using TCPDF and now what is that i want to save that generated PDF of table A1 to table A2 And Retrieve that PDF from table A2.

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_put_contents` function for that.